# data Frame to dictionary

Tags: pandas

I can create a new dataframe based on the list of dicts. But how do I get the same list back from dataframe?

```
mylist=[{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'}, 
{'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'}]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

The following will return the dictionary as per column and not row as shown in the example above.

```
n [18]: df.to_dict()
Out[18]:
{'month': {0: nan, 1: 'february', 2: 'january', 3: 'june'},
 'points': {0: 50.0, 1: 25.0, 2: 90.0, 3: nan},
 'points_h1': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 20.0},
 'time': {0: '5:00', 1: '6:00', 2: '9:00', 3: nan},
 'year': {0: 2010.0, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_dict(outtype='records')
```

Answer is from from: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html